# How can I login with 100 different users in the web application simultaneously and then each user performs different functions in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing, parallel-execution

I dont anything about JMeter, but i wanted to ask if this thing is possible in JMeter.

1. 100 users with different username/password login in concurrently in the web application.
2. Each user stays logged in the product, do specific functions, operations, then log out.

Also, will Jmeter open a new browser window of each user login at the same time?

Now, can i achieve the functional steps in Jmeter? How will i enter locators of the web elements. I have made a login script with Selenium webdriver, but can i  use a plugin with selenium to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jmeter does not operate with real browsers. It only simulates signals to the server like they would be sent if you would use real browser.

However it is possible to buld the scenario you've described in your question. It requires pretty much basic knowledge so you can easily find tutorial in Google.

**UPD:** there is the way to integrate webdriver script into JMeter using plugins like [Webdriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), however it is hardly possible to take your existing code and copy-paste to jmeter sampler. You will likely have to do a lot of rework (easier is to start from scratch). Another point is that it is likely intended to test a one-user scenario to assess how fast your client-side scripts work. If you run scenario for 100 hundred parallel users your environment will likely die in agony.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! that means JMeter can never open the web application in a browser window/tab and it will just do it's stuff behind the scene. Ok. Also, can I somehow integrate my "Login" script in selenium webdriver with Jmeter, so that i can load test 100 users concurrently?

Comment: @danny67 please check my update

Comment: @danny67 _that means JMeter can never open the web application in a browser window/tab_  not like that it is possible to open the browser. for that you need to integrate selenium with JMeter. I did the demo earlier. Things is that you need to go through functionality and concept of JMeter and use it as per your requirement

Comment: ok, Thanks a lot @ NarendraR, for clarifying this. Could you refer me to some good reference material for this!